# Concatenate all sheet files and create one new column with sheet names in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xlrd

Given a excel file [test.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9l6cnq2fido1la/test.xlsx?dl=0) which has many sheets: `1.DC`, `2.SH` and `3.GZ`, etc.

```
import xlrd
dfs = xlrd.open_workbook('./test.xlsx', on_demand = True)
print(dfs.sheet_names())
```

Out:

```
['1.DC', '2.SH', '3.GZ']
```

How could I read and concatenate all the sheets and create a new column with sheet names while removing `1., 2., 3., etc.` in the starting part of each sheet names?

The expected result will like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with `sheet_name=None` for convert all sheets to `DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

dfs = {k: v.loc[:, ~v.columns.str.contains('Unnamed')] for k, v in dfs.items()}

# print(dfs)
```

Then if need one column use lsit comparehension with select this column, here `name`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(x, k) for k, v in dfs.items() for x in v['name']], 
                  columns=['name','city'])
df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace('^[0-9\.]+', '')
print (df)
      name    city
0    James      DC
1     Bond      DC
2   Steven      DC
3   Walker      SH
4      Tom      SH
5   Filler      GZ
6   Cooker      GZ
7      Tim      GZ
```

Or if need all columns omit `[name]` here:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
print(dfs) 

df = (pd.concat(dfs)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('city')['name']
        .reset_index())
df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace('^[0-9\.]+', '')
print (df)
      city    name
0       DC   James
1       DC    Bond
2       DC  Steven
3       SH  Walker
4       SH     Tom
5       GZ  Filler
6       GZ  Cooker
7       GZ     Tim
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to ignore `Unnamed columns` when I read data? I find in each sheet there are many: `Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  ..., etc.`

Comment: @ahbon - hmmm, how looks real columns names? All are `unamed` ?

Comment: Except `name` for each sheets, there are other columns `Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  ...  Unnamed: 58  Unnamed: 59  Unnamed: 60`.

Comment: @ahbon - I got it, add secon dlike of code `dfs= {k: v.loc[:, ~v.columns.str.contains('Unnamed')] for k, v in dfs.items()}` filter out columns with `unnamed`